# Creating shareable Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

On IBM Watson studio, how do I create a Jupyter notebook on Watson studio without an IBM analytics engine like Spark service?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link and update your question accordingly. What have you investigated?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking how to create notebook for spark given spark service is deprecated.
You can create new notebooks using Spark Environments that provided by watson studio.
You need to create a project in watson studio first. Then follow below:-

1. Click Add to Project -> Notebook
2. In the drop-down, select runtime as "Default Spark Python 3.6 XS or sparkR or scala". You can also create custom environment defintion for spark runtime based on the number of executors or memory requirements you have and once you create those, new notebook will show those runtimes in the dropdown menu.
   https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/spark-envs.html?audience=wdp&context=wdp
3. Once you have created the notebook, simply share it using share icon you see in the notebook.